# Python add number to dict

Tags: python, django

I use Django 1.8. I have a table "Table". I want to make it loot at this:

```
test['Kamil'] += 1
test['Wiesiek'] +=1
```

finally has look to like this - for example:

```
test['Kamil'] = 10
test['Wiesiek'] = 5

Data = Table.objects.filter(User=request.user.username)

        test = {}
        for i in Data:
            test[i.Name] += 1
```

Unfortunelly django show me a error.. KeyError at /page/

If I not have instead "+=" - "=" then all works.

I need to count how many of the same names occur. I have access to the names and the number of

Thanks :)

Comment: instead of `test = {}`, try `test = collections.Counter()` (you will need to `import collections`)

Comment: What's the structure of the objects in the `Data` queryset?

Answer (score 3):

Your dictionary does not have a value for the key when you attempt to +=

You can use a defaultdict from collections which will set a default value of 0 to new keys

```
from collections import defaultdict
Data = Table.objects.filter(User=request.user.username)
    test = defaultdict(int)
    for i in Data:
        test[i.Name] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the key exists first

```
test['Kamil'] = 10
test['Wiesiek'] = 5

Data = Table.objects.filter(User=request.user.username)

        test = {}
        for i in Data:
            if test.get(i.Name, None):
                test[i.Name] += 1
            else:
                test[i.Name] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you forgetting to put the key in the dictionary first?  E.G.

```
test = {}
for i in Data:
    if i.Name not in test:
       test[i.Name] = 1
    else:
       test[i.Name] += 1
```